# C, pass to function by reference. Pass forward

Tags: c, pointers

I understood the meaning of passing by reference and by value in C, but in my program I would like to "pass forward" the reference to another function, for neatness purposes, for instance:

```
void f2(int *x2)
{
   *x2 = 7;
}

void f1(int *x1)
{
   *x1 = 4;
    f2(x1);
}

int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  f1(&x);
  printf("%d\n",x);
  return 1;
}
```

Does the main function print out 4 or 7?
Moreover, if I would like to be sure to pass the reference to `f2` inside `f1` , my idea was to do:

```
void f1(int *x1)
{
   *x1 = 4;

    int x2;
    &x2 = x1;
    f2(&x2);
}
```

But I don't find it that elegant and fast (in my program I use instead of `int` some pretty big `structs` and I would like to avoid creating a copy inside every function). Does my soultion work anyway? Is there a more elegant and faster way?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I tested it and the first snippet does compile and works as expected (main prints out 7). So first method is the right way. The second code snippet is wrong and does not compile

Comment: `Does the main function print out 4 or 7?`..why don;t you try?

Comment: There is no such thing as reference in C.

Comment: "*But I don't find it that elegant and fast*" - who cares if it doesn't even compile?

Comment: C is pass-by-value only. you can trick it using pointers, but it is pass-by-value.

Comment: Right, there is no references in C. Only pointers. Ponters AND references are supported in C++.

Comment: Ok sorry everyone, I tried and prints out 7

Comment: @CarloBenussi the `f1` function in the second snippet doesn't make sense, and it won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

In C, there's neither a *reference* nor is there a *pass by reference* concept. Arguments are **always** passed by value.

You can emulate *pass by reference* semantics using pointers. Of course, you can pass on that pointer. The pointer itself is passed by value (see my first paragraph), so each function has its own copy. But this value (the address it points to) doesn't change, so each function can access the data the pointer points to.

---

Your second code snippet doesn't make any sense. It's impossible to change the address of a variable. And, as you should've understood from the rest of my answer, whatever you tried there is unnecessary anyways.

Comment: I DV the answer (and I did read it :) ). With all due respect to a 12k user, your answer is more suitable as a comment. Since I started using this website I have always been told not to answer such silly questions on SO, as it encourages people to ask silly questions.

Comment: I actually found out how silly my question was a minute after I posted it, since not only I could answer it to myself by testing it (I was from mobile but ok), but the question was very basic. I think I earned the DV, but appreciate also @FelixPalmen for having aswered it

Comment: the 2nd snippet doesn't make sense and also fails at compilation - _error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment_

Comment: @CIsForCookies I chose the wording *it's impossible to change the address of a variable* in favor of *the address-of operator doesn't yield an lvalue* because I think the former will be easier to understand at a beginner level ;)

Comment: @RyanB. Down-voting due to "the question shouldn't have been answered because it is a silly question" instead of judging the quality of the answer, is even more silly than an answering a silly question.